# How check connect from client when not run server in socket.io (node.js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I use node.js and socket.io to get data from mysql. I has connected sussessfully to mysql.
File server.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
var monitorio = require('monitor.io')
io.use(monitorio({ port: 8000 }));
var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password : '12345678',
  database: 'test'
})

db.connect(function(err){
  if (err) console.log(err)
})

var socketCount = 0

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socketCount++
  io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socketCount--
    io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)
  })

  socket.on('get customer', function(data){
    console.log('request to server : ' + data);
    db.query('select CUSTOMER_NAME from customers where TELEPHONE = ?', data)
        .on('result', function(data){
            console.log('server response to client : ' + data.CUSTOMER_NAME);
            socket.emit('get customer', data)
        })
  })
})
```

And at client i has imported :

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

When i run server.js

```
node server.js
```

Everything is ok. I can get data from mysql. But i suppose when computer does not run nodejs or any error to nodejs, i want client not get data from mysql. But when i stop **server.js** had an error occurs with javascipt code at client.
[image: log lost connect socket.io]
......And error in javascript client :
[image: error socket io in client]

How can i know lost connect at port:3000 at server to ignore javascript in picture 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're importing the io code, here's my client-side socket initialisation using require.js:

```
var io = require('io');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function() {console.log('Connected');})
      .on('connect_error', function() {console.log('Conn error');})
      .on('disconnect', function() {console.log('Disconnected'); });
```

You can then check the connection status using:

```
if (socket.connected) doSomething();
```

Also, instead of using your own count, `var socketCount = 0`, you can use the following in node:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connected clients: " + io.engine.clientsCount);
}
```